# GPUImageView hanging on presentFrameBuffer when OpenGL Profiler attached

Tags: macos, opengl, gpuimage

I've submitted an issue on the `GPUImage` github page, but thought I would see if anyone here has a workaround or a better idea of the cause of the problem.

I have a `GPUImageView` fed by `GPUImageRawDataInput` in an OS X application.  If I attach `OpenGL Profiler` and turn tracing on while updating, processing gets stuck in `[NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer]` (specifically in `__psynch_mutexwait`).  For a simple test case, I just have a view controller with a button and custom view of class `GPUImageView` and the following code in the controller:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSString *fname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestImage" ofType:@"dat"];
    NSError *err = nil;
    if(!fname){
        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ViewController" code:0
                              userInfo:@{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey:@"No selected data file!"}];
    }else{
        _rawDataFromFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fname
                                                  options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe | NSDataReadingUncached
                                                    error:&err];
    }
    if(err){
        [self presentError:err];
        return;
    }
    [self.imageView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio];
    [self.imageView setBackgroundColorRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    GLubyte* data = (GLubyte *)[self.rawDataFromFile bytes];
    _inputFilter = [[GPUImageRawDataInput alloc] initWithBytes:data
                                                          size:CGSizeMake(1024, 241)
                                                   pixelFormat:GPUPixelFormatLuminance
                                                          type:GPUPixelTypeUByte];
    [self.inputFilter addTarget:self.imageView];
}

- (IBAction)updateAction:(id)sender {
    if (_inputFilter) {
        [self.inputFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [self.inputFilter processData];
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this might hang *only when the profiler is attached*?  Thanks!

I'm running on a mid 2012 macbook pro, OS X 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized a mistake in my "simple" test case which solves my problem. It points out a potential solution to other problems people might have with `GPUImage` in OS X apps, so I'm posting it as a solution here.

If you use Interface Builder to place your `GPUImageView` inside an `NSView`, make sure you turn the parent view's `Core Animation Layer` off unless you explicitly need it and know what you are doing (it is on by default).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem—not with GPUImage but just trying to trace my app using the OpenGL Profiler. My solution was to switch from using a subclass of `NSOpenGLView` to using a subclass of `NSView` with an `NSOpenGLLayer` as its layer. After that change, I can trace with the profiler without hanging.